# Where to store BlazeJS component variables (template instance or data context)?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

Here is a bit of UI code, where i'm trying to set some default values for data, passed from smart component:

```
Template.selector.onCreated(function() {
  const template = this,
        data = this.data;

  _.defaults(data, {
    inputValue: new ReactiveVar(),
    showDropOnFocus: true,
    showDropOnDblClick: true
  })

  const drop = template.drop = {
    shown: new ReactiveVar()
  };

  const input = template.input = {
    hasFocus: new ReactiveVar(),
    hasValue: new ReactiveVar(),
    wasDblClicked: new ReactiveVar()
  };

  ...
})
```

But it feels quite disambiguous for me, to store some component variables in data context, while the others in template instance.

So, is it a right way:

1. To modify data context, while this property marked as readonly in
   BlazeJS [docs](http://blazejs.org/api/templates.html#Blaze-TemplateInstance-data)?
2. To pass with data reactive variables, defined at toplevel
   component?

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed yourself, `data` context should not be modified. It's common practice to store any reactive variables in the template instance itself. Usually, the `onCreated` is the best place to do that.